# Slow-producer, fast-consumer IEnumerable wrapper

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm hoping that you kind people could cast an eye over my code and let me know what you think... Have I missed something obvious? Are there any possible race conditions? Is there an entirely different and/or better way to do this? Good and bad, everything is appreciated!

So, I have to produce and consume lots of *something*, however the producers are extremely slow and the consumption of the items extremely fast. **slow producers, fast consumer**

Thankfully my current problem can have the production of items parallelized to some extent, so I have written a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, takes a bunch of `IEnumerable<T>`s in it's constructor and exposes their combined output. The idea being that I am breaking the problem into parallelizable chunks, and feeding each in to be (behind-the-scenes) enumerated in parallel.

The code is probably more instructive than my babbling sentences above:

```cs
// The ability to limit the number of cached items is in case we have the unexpected
// case of producing items faster than we can consume
class ParallelProducer<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IEnumerable<T>[] enumerables;
    private readonly int maxItemsToCache;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    private ParallelProducer(int maxItemsToCache, IEnumerable<T>[] enumerables)
    {
        this.maxItemsToCache = maxItemsToCache;
        this.enumerables = enumerables;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ParallelProducerEnumerator<T>(this.maxItemsToCache, this.enumerables);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested types

    private class ParallelProducerEnumerator<U> : IEnumerator<U>
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly List<Thread> producerThreads;
        int threadsStillEnumerating;
        private bool producersStarted = false;

        private readonly BlockingCollection<U> cachedItems;
        private U currentItem;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public ParallelProducerEnumerator(int maxItemsToCache, IEnumerable<U>[] slowEnumerables)
        {
            this.cachedItems = new BlockingCollection<U>(maxItemsToCache);

            this.producerThreads = new List<Thread>();
            this.threadsStillEnumerating = slowEnumerables.Length;

            // this variable will be captured by all of the thread methods
            foreach (var slowEnumerable in slowEnumerables)
            {
                // to avoid a reference to the iterator variable being captured
                var enumerableToCapture = slowEnumerable;

                var thread = new Thread(() => ProducerMethod(enumerableToCapture));
                this.producerThreads.Add(thread);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public U Current
        {
            get { return this.currentItem; }
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return this.Current; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void ProducerMethod(IEnumerable<U> enumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                this.cachedItems.Add(item);
            }

            int postDecrementValue = Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.threadsStillEnumerating);
            if (postDecrementValue == 0)
            {
                cachedItems.CompleteAdding();
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (!producersStarted)
            {
                producersStarted = true;
                foreach (var thread in producerThreads)
                {
                    thread.Start();
                }
            }

            if (!cachedItems.TryTake(out this.currentItem, Timeout.Infinite))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And a little example usage for good measure...

```cs
// a slow producer...
static IEnumerable<int> SlowGetNumbers(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        yield return i;
    }
}

// a fast consumer
static void Consume(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

var vanillaProducer = SlowGetNumbers(1, 30);
var parallelProducer = new ParallelProducer<int>(
    SlowGetNumbers(1, 10),
    SlowGetNumbers(10, 20),
    SlowGetNumbers(20, 30));

// This will take 3 seconds
Consume(vanillaProducer);

// This will take ~1 second
Consume(parallelProducer);
```

#### Edit

On svick's advice, I'm just creating a `IEnumerator<T>`-returning method, and it's far simpler and has far less boilerplate...

```cs
static class ParallelProducer
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Create<T>(int maxItemsToCache, params IEnumerable<T>[] enumerables)
    {
        BlockingCollection<T> cachedItems = new BlockingCollection<T>(maxItemsToCache);
        int threadsStillEnumerating = enumerables.Length;

        foreach (var slowEnumerable in enumerables)
        {
            // to avoid a reference to the iterator variable being captured
            var enumerableToCapture = slowEnumerable;

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                foreach (var item in enumerableToCapture)
                {
                    cachedItems.Add(item);
                }

                int postDecrementValue = Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadsStillEnumerating);
                if (postDecrementValue == 0)
                {
                    cachedItems.CompleteAdding();
                }
            });
            thread.Start();
        }

        return cachedItems.GetConsumingEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can use .Net 4.5, problems like this can be solved very easily using TPL Dataflow.

Comment: @svick any good sample using TPL Dataflow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems fine and thread-safe to me. Few things to think about:

1. You're using lots of threads that could block in the unlikely case when the consumer is slow. Doing things asynchronously could help you there, but it's most likely not worth it, because it would be quite complicated (unless you could use C# 5).
2. I would usually prefer `Task`s to `Thread`s, but in your case that doesn't give you much. So I think using `Thread`s here directly is fine.
3. If your producers are slow, why do you wait until you start them until the call to `MoveNext()`? I think starting them in the constructor would make more sense here.
4. You could avoid all of the boilerplate `IEnumerator<T>` code by using [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) (in that case, you would probably change your constructor to an `IEnumerator<T>`-returning method). This has the added benefit that you could more easily modify your code for multiple consumer threads in the future.

Comment: For 3, I didn't feel quite right kicking it all off in the constructor (I never like doing too much in there), but I think you might be right. As for 4, that's perfect, a failure to read the docs thoroughly enough on my part... All good food for thought though, thanks!